# Laravel getting empty query

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5

I have a model called Region, which can have many countries. I want to get them, but when i use the query output to see why it does not find anything, i get an empty query [].

Here is my Region method:

```
public function countries() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Country', 'country_region_relation', 'country_id', 'region_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
public function countries() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Country');
}
```

I see your scenario to be a many to many relationship. so if the above does not work try this

```
public function countries() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Country', 'country_region_relation', 'country_id', 'region_id');
}
```